# Using HTML or any markup language for the views in iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface

Programatically implementing interfaces on iOS is too verbose in my opinion. Sure, you could do it in IB but I fancy reusing my code and I hate having to change one thing in 10 different places or spreading my interface in 100 IB files to avoid that. Also, IB is very slow, although I own a new generation Macbook Pro, I still have to wait 3-4 seconds to open large files, not to mention the lack of zoom and the general clumsiness makes me run when I hear about it.

Now, to the question at hand, is there any open source effort or otherwise a way to describe the layout (not necessarily the view "logic"), just the layout in HTML or any other markup language.

So far I've seen that `CALayer` has a `style` property that could be used, however, it doesn't support positioning. Also, I tried to use `UIWebView` but it seems to force me to have my logic inside HTML code as well, which I don't want to, plus, it's slower.

What else could I try?

Comment: `UIAppearance` and subclassing can mitigate some of the "10 different places" problem. IB has zooming, so I'm not understanding your point there. On speed issue, if you leave storyboard open on it's own tab, it reduces the 3-4 second delay to be a "once per session" problem". Still, I wish you luck in your hunt for a replacement. Just count yourself lucky that you're not doing Android, because while I do a lot of Xcode/IB stuff on my first gen Air, Eclipse is borderline unusable.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for your comment. IB has zooming? How do you zoom? (I mean, pixel level like Photoshop, so you can arrange objects). I tried the middle mouse wheel with no luck. Anyway, not trying to replace xCode, although it is slow (had to de-activate live indexing the other day to get it work at the level of responsiveness I like), I just want to find an easier/faster/portable way to write the interface.

Comment: @Meda Ah, no, we're talking different kind of zooming. :) I was talking about zooming out, which is very useful when stepping back and looking at the whole storyboard, picking a particular scene, etc. You can do that zoom out with the magnifying class button in the lower right corner, or by pinching on your trackpad. Sorry. I misunderstood what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at [Nimbus CSS](http://docs.nimbuskit.info/NimbusCSS.html). It does exactly what you're looking for in CSS. It supports positioning and it's pretty stable.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is a couple of years old, but in case anyone else is looking for something similar, take a look at MarkupKit:

https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit

It's an open-source framework I created that allows you to build native iOS apps in markup. For example, you can create a label instance like this:

```
<UILabel text="Hello, World" font="System 24" textColor="#ff0000"/>
```

rather than this:

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel new];

[label setText:@"Hello, World"];
[label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

It also supports dynamic localization and CSS-like styling, among other things.

Complete project documentation can be found here:

https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit/blob/master/README.md

Examples and other information are available in the wiki:

https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit/wiki

Hope you find it useful.